# Update Master Workbook via multiple independent sheets from other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master Workbook with several labelled sheets. I am trying to update sheets in this workbooks named: 949, div and active pl.

The data for each of these 3 sheets would be pulled from 3 child workbooks, named accordingly as 949.xlsx, div.xlsx and activepl.xlsx. These workbooks have only 1 sheet in each of them.

How do I clear existing data except the header row then copy all the data from each of the child workbooks (disregarding the first row which is the header), into the respectively named sheets in the Master Workbook?

The macro I have so far:

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents


    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this is superh handy in that it has a pop up box allowing you to specify the directory of the child workbooks to loop through.

Comment: [949.xlsx][1]
[activepl][2]
[Master file: A-8][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/itRT5.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2KRg.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68aQD.png

I am trying to update the sheets in the Master file A-8 with the data in the 3 seperate workbooks; without the headers. For example 949.xlsx would go to sheet 949 in A-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim vName As Variant, vDB As Variant
    Dim Master As Workbook, Target As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Master = ThisWorkbook

    vName = Array("949", "div", "activepl")
    'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
          .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
      myPath = myPath
      If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While myFile <> ""
        For i = 0 To 2
            If InStr(myFile, vName(i)) Then


            'Set variable equal to opened workbook
              Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
                vDB = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)
                Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear '<~~ Clear cells except head
                Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
            'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
              DoEvents


            'Save and Close Workbook
              wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

            'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
              DoEvents
            End If
        Next i
            'Get next file name
              myFile = Dir
      Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
      'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You can change the position by giving the condition according to the sheet name.

```
        If vName(i) = "activepl" Then
            Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1, 1).Clear '<~~ Clear cells except head
            Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
        Else
            Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear '<~~ Clear cells except head
            Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
        End If
```

Edition

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
    Dim vName As Variant, vDB As Variant
    Dim Master As Workbook, Target As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Master = ThisWorkbook

    vName = Array("949", "div", "activepl")
    'Optimize Macro Speed
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
      Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        With FldrPicker
          .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
            myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
      myPath = myPath
      If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
      Do While myFile <> ""
        For i = 0 To 2
            If InStr(myFile, vName(i)) Then

            'Set variable equal to opened workbook
              Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

                vDB = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)

                If vName(i) = "activepl" Then
                    Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1, 1).Clear '<~~ Clear cells except head
                    Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
                Else
                    Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear '<~~ Clear cells except head
                    Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
                End If
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
            'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
              DoEvents


            'Save and Close Workbook
              wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

            'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
              DoEvents
            End If
        Next i
            'Get next file name
              myFile = Dir
      Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
      MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
      'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code works beautifully.
May I ask how to could modify the code clear the existing cells under the headers in the masterWB before copying over?
RIght now it pastes the new data below the existing instead of overwriting

Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, what if for activepl  I need to paste into b2 (offset first row and A column)? Would I create 2 arrays, with activepl in the second?

Comment: @Raja, **Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear**   I  edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I really appreciate it!. Sorry for being unclear, I meant that 949 and div would be pasted into A2 like the original code; but activepl would be going into B2

Comment: Does this mix of code make sense? I can't quite get this to work

vName = Array("949", "div", "activepl")
vName2 = Array("activepl")
vNameall = Array(vName, vName2)
              Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
                vDB = wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1)
                Master.Sheets(vNameall(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear

Comment: Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) 
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName2(i)).Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) 
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

Comment: Hi! The condition works for activepl, but for some reason on pasting, the entire of column A, (except cell A1) has lost its formatting and fill. 

Is this due to the line: 
Set Target = Master.Sheets(vName(i)).Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2) '<~~ column b
                Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

would you be so kind to explain the logic of that code so I may learn from you and can make future changes? Thank you!

Comment: @Raja,  Use  ClearContent  instead  Çlear.  **Master.Sheets(vName(i)).UsedRange.Offset(1, 1).ClearContent**

Comment: @Raja, Above example use variant array to get  value. You have to  copy method for  formatting and the other.

Comment: How do I adapt this code where I am only picking out specific sheets from the child workbooks? 949.xlsx has sheets: 'Sheet 1' and '949 report' ; i want to copy out 949 report and paste in to 949 report sheet in Master